# Using recycle on Domino object causes bean to not return data

Tags: java, javabeans, xpages

I have a session scoped bean that reads the contents of a view and stores a hashmap of SelectItem objects. These are then used to populate combobox values on an XPage.

The code works fine EXCEPT when I try to recycle a ViewEntry object in the innermost loop. If the line is commented out, I get my SelectItems returned fine. If the line is uncommented, my comboboxes are empty. So what I'd like to know is:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix this and correctly recycle the object like a good developer should?
3. If I can't explicitly recycle the object, what is the potential impact on memory etc?

Code (with problem line highlighted and currently commented out):

```
public class comboBox extends HashMap<String, List<SelectItem>> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public comboBox() {
        this.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Database database = null;
        View vwData = null;
        ViewNavigator navData = null;
        try {
            PrimeUser thisUser = (PrimeUser) resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "PrimeUser");
            String lang = thisUser.getLang();
            database = getCurrentDatabase();
            vwData = database.getView("DataLookup");
            navData = vwData.createViewNavFromCategory(lang);
            ViewEntry keyCat = navData.getFirst();
            ViewEntry nextCat = null;
            while (keyCat != null) {
                String thisKey = (String) keyCat.getColumnValues().get(1);
                List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                options.add(new SelectItem("Please select..."));
                ViewEntry dataEntry = navData.getChild(keyCat);
                ViewEntry nextChild = null;
                while (dataEntry != null) {
                    nextChild = navData.getNextSibling();
                    Object optValue = dataEntry.getColumnValues().get(2);
                    String optLabel = (String) dataEntry.getColumnValues().get(3);
                    options.add(new SelectItem(optValue, optLabel));

                    // dataEntry.recycle(); //<---- PROBLEM HERE

                    dataEntry = nextChild;
                }
                this.put(thisKey, options);
                nextCat = navData.getNextCategory();
                keyCat.recycle();
                keyCat = nextCat;
            }
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                navData.recycle();
                vwData.recycle();
                database.recycle();
            } catch (NotesException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public List<SelectItem> get(String key) {
        return this.get(key);
    }
}
```

RESOLVED:

The resolution was annoyingly simple (and thanks to Sven Hasselbach for reminding me to review the Server log output again). The change was straightforward - exchange this line:

```
            nextCat = navData.getNextCategory();
```

for this:

```
            nextCat = getNextSibling(keyCat);
```

Although "getNextCategory" is a method of ViewNavigator and does not have any parameters; it only gets the next category following the current entry. If the current entry has been recycled - as was the case above - then obviously the current entry is null and the method throws an exception.

"getNextSibling" has an optional ViewEntry parameter which, if specified, will override the pointer to the current ViewEntry that it would otherwise use.

I blame Fridays.

Comment: Domino objects cannot be serialised. So there is no guarantee that the code will work as expected putting it into the sessionScope.

Comment: None of the Domino objects are being kept as properties of the bean so Serialization is, as far as I can tell, not the issue. But the bean has been tested in viewScope with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

First look at your server console: Do you see a NotesException there? If you run into the Exception, your *put* will never be executed, so your comboboxes will be empty.

Before you recycle an object, you have to test if it is *null*, surrounded by a try/catch block. There are some implementations for an easier recycling of Notes objects, f.e. this one http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=recycleobject-helper-for-recycling-of-objects

A good explanation about recycling can be found here: http://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/recycle-and-the-retail-experience/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sven. I understand the whys and wherefores of recycle (and generally use recycle helpers that I did't put in this code for clarity reasons) but that new article by Nathan explains it better than I probably could. I had forgotten to add the details of the exception because this has been bugging me for ages - looking again, I think it's less to do with the recycling of the NotesEntry object and more losing the pointer to the navData ViewNavigator object. I'm having an absolute mindblank as to why this is happening and how to code for it.